# How can I create a unique URL to Firebase path for sharing using AngularFire?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, unique-key

So I have been researching this for quiet a while but I cannot seem to find the correct answer anywhere. I have an idea and I want users to create a list of items and then save this, return a link and share this link. I already know how to return the `key()` in firebase so that should not be an issue.

My firebase data would look something like this

```
----Unique id

       ---item:"item1"
       ---item:"item2" 

----Unique id

       ---item:"item1"
       ---item:"item2"
```

How can I get it so that when people hit the save button they get back an URL like this to share: `http://www.example.org/-uniqueID`. And when other people go to that link they get the correct shared data from that link.

I am sorry I don't have any code for you. I understand the firebase (AngularFire) basics, but this is new to me and I have trouble understanding how to do this.

Can someone point me in the right direction?
It would mean a lot.TIA

**edit**

This works:

```
angular.module("app", ["firebase", "ui.router"])

.controller('liveCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $firebaseObject) {
    console.log($stateParams);

   var fb = new Firebase('https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/' + $stateParams.uniqueID + '');
    console.log(fb);

   $scope.list = $firebaseObject(fb);
   $scope.list.$loaded().then(console.log($scope.list));


})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("home");

  $stateProvider

  .state('live', {
        url: '/live/:uniqueID',
        templateUrl: 'live.html',
        controller: 'liveCtrl'
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what your architecture looks like, but what you can do is have the user create a list, then have the user set a unique ID or (slug) in an input field - save that specific data in Firebase.

Then in your **APP.JS** - Define a route based on that unique ID

*For Example*

```
.state('live', {
        url: '/live/:uniqueID',
        templateUrl: 'views/live.html',
        controller: 'liveCtrl'
    })
```

*FYI : The best way is to have a 'resolve' above so the data loads before the controller activates.*

Then in your controller, if you are using a ui-router, get the $stateParam, and set it in your firebase URL.

```
.controller('liveCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {

    var fb = new Firebase('https://firebaseio.com/data/' + $stateParams.param + '');

    // Return the data | Set it in a $scope

})
```

You can then give the user a URL to share : http://example.com/live/myuniqueid

Let me know if your still confused!

Comment: Hmm, no this is not exactly whay I want to do. I want to use the `$add` method in angularFire and that will create an unique key automatically, get this key back and use it in the URL, but you may have me pushed in the right direction going with $stateParams. I will see if I can find the time coming up with an example.

Comment: No problem, let me know if you need any help!

Comment: Will get to work soon and let you know if I can figure it out! Thanks!

Comment: Ok I have figured it out. You definetly set me in the right direction. Opens a whole new world for me :)...Can you explain me how to use resolve in this context. I tried resolving the promise, but I can't add parameters to the URL in the resolve function. So it fails. But this works however, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

When you call $add, firebase returns a promise with the key name, which will allow you to use that uniqueid in your url.  the uniqueid will be the same as the key()

*from angularfire docs*

```
var list = $firebaseArray(ref);
list.$add({ foo: "bar" }).then(function(ref) {
var id = ref.key();
console.log("added record with id " + id);
list.$indexFor(id); // returns location in the array
});
```

Comment: Yes I as I already stated I know the basics and I was not clear in my question that I already know how to return the key. Now the trick to use it in the URL, but I think with the other answer I will get close to where I want to be :)...Thanks anyway